# Rails 5 autoloading issue in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hard time understanding an issue with Rails autoloading.

So I have a controller which is located in a folder named `api`. The constroller is declared as `class Api::TestController`.

In another folder, I have a file called `app/my_folder/service_name/api.rb`

In production, I get this error : `load_missing_constant': Unable to autoload constant Api, expected /app/my_folder/service_name/api.rb to define it (LoadError)`

`application.rb` has this line :

```rb
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'my_folder', '{**/}')]
```

I have no issues in development.

Why is this happening ?

Comment: A [common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103333/unable-to-autoload-constant-api-controller-in-rails-4) is `inflections` with acronyms like API. Do you have any inflections defined in an initializer?

Comment: Why do you perform autolading and not eagor loading in production? Have you added the same folder to `config.eager_load_paths`?

Comment: @BroiSatse autoloading is not be performed in production - thats exactly the problem.

Comment: @max IIRC, with autoloading disabled it would be a simple NameError exception, but here it tried to load that constant which suggest that they have, for whatever reason, autoloading enabled in production. As you noted already, having a wildcard in an autoload path is quite a suicide! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its happening since the auto load paths are only used for auto loading. In order for your class to be loaded in production you need to augment the `eager_load_paths` as well:

```
config.eager_load_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'my_folder', '{**/}')]
```

However this isn't exactly a great practice - any directory in `app` is automatically used as a root directory. What you're doing is adding every subdirectory of a given directory as root directories.

Using the scope resultion operator (`class Api::TestController`) for [namespace definition](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition) should also be avoided as it leads to suprising constant lookup behavior and is the source of autoloading bugs. Instead you should nest the class explicitly and setup an inflection [for the acronym](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#camelcase-classes):

```
# config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end

# every time you use Api as a constant name a kitten dies.
module API
  class TestController
    puts Module.nesting.inspect # [TestController::API, API] 
  end
end
```

Comment: Your answer is right. After reading about autoloading, I think that the real issue is the fact that class Api::TestController is not declared with a module. When trying to resolve the parent namespace, rails hits Api which is not defined anywhere, so it starts looking in the autoload_paths and finds the app/my_folder/service_name/api.rb file which is expected to define the module or class Api.

Comment: Yeah thats one of the issues with missusing the scope resolution operator. The second is that if you for example reference `Foo` inside the class it will not find `Api::Foo` since the module nesting is not properly set.